# Break in foreach with certain conditions

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, break

I've some problem with my school assignment. I'm confused about manipulation array because of little experience. I'm using `foreach` to get value from array and then I want to result this with certain condition, among others:

1. the number of words that are already in a set variable `$total_words`
2. There are conditions in `foreach`. **if** `$total words` not passing the number of words in the array values, prints all array values. But to **else** to break all and then word stop by the last number of words.

For more details you can see the results that I want

```
$array = array(
  "There are many ways to get to Windows 10 Advanced Startup Options.",
  "On many laptops, hitting F11 as soon as you power on will get you there.",
  "Booting off an install disk and hitting Next then Repair will do the job",
  "n ....................."
);

$total_words = 4;

foreach($array as $value){
  $count = explode(" ", $value);
  if( count($count) <= $total_words){
    echo $value. "\n\n";
  } else {
    //echo i do something
    break;
  }
}

//output $total_words = 4;
/* There are many */

//output $total_words = 12;
/* There are many ways to get to Windows 10 Advanced Startup Options. */

//output $total_words = 16;
/* There are many ways to get to Windows 10 Advanced Startup Options. */
/* On many laptops, hitting */

//output $total_words = 20000;
/* There are many ways to get to Windows 10 Advanced Startup Options. */
/* On many laptops, hitting F11 as soon as you power on will get you there. */
/* Booting off an install disk and hitting Next then Repair will do the job */
/* n ..................... */
```

Comment: Lucky please revisit your abandoned questions.  Respond to requests for details in your questions.  Accept best answers when you receive satisfactory answers.  Clarify your questions when you don't receive satisfactory answers.

Comment: Oke sir.. it seems, your answer is right for me to finish my school assignment. thanks sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the method that I would use -- assuming I understand the question.  Check the word count on each iteration and truncate the text or reduce the word allowance as needed.

Code: (Demo:  https://3v4l.org/JFYsd  )

```
function word_limiter($sentences,$word_allowance){
    $text='';
    foreach($sentences as $sentence){
        $words=explode(' ',$sentence);
        $word_count=count($words);
        if($word_count>$word_allowance){
            $text.=implode(' ',array_slice($words,0,$word_allowance));
            // do something
            break;
        }elseif($word_count==$word_allowance){
            $text.=$sentence;
            break;
        }else{
            $text.="$sentence\n";
            $word_allowance-=$word_count;  // reduce allowance for next iteration
        }
    }
    return $text;
}

$array = array(
  "There are many ways to get to Windows 10 Advanced Startup Options.",
  "On many laptops, hitting F11 as soon as you power on will get you there.",
  "Booting off an install disk and hitting Next then Repair will do the job",
  "n ....................."
);

echo word_limiter($array,4),"\n\n";
echo word_limiter($array,12),"\n\n";
echo word_limiter($array,16),"\n\n";
echo word_limiter($array,27),"\n\n";
```

Output:

```
There are many ways

There are many ways to get to Windows 10 Advanced Startup Options.

There are many ways to get to Windows 10 Advanced Startup Options.
On many laptops, hitting

There are many ways to get to Windows 10 Advanced Startup Options.
On many laptops, hitting F11 as soon as you power on will get you there.
```